# Is there an Emacs function that copies a whole line including the newline?

Tags: emacs, copy, newline

I can't write emacs function, could anyone help me?.

Comment: Do you mean a elisp function that returns the current line, or a function that is intended to be called interactively which places the line on the current yank buffer (like M-w)?

Comment: If you look around for 'nuke-line', you might find a defun some where on the Internet.  I have it at my work .emacs, not here at home.  But it cuts the present line including the newline, not copy it.  The line could still be accessed by `C-y`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. [This code is borrowed from this blog entry](http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/11/copying-lines-without-selecting-them.html):

```
(defadvice kill-ring-save (before slick-copy activate compile)
  "When called interactively with no active region, copy a single line instead."
  (interactive
    (if mark-active (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (message "Copied line")
      (list (line-beginning-position)
        (line-beginning-position 2)))))

(defadvice kill-region (before slick-cut activate compile)
  "When called interactively with no active region, kill a single line instead."
  (interactive
    (if mark-active (list (region-beginning) (region-end))
      (list (line-beginning-position)
        (line-beginning-position 2)))))
```

Comment: I think the following code could help me. (defun duplicate-line()
  (interactive)
  (move-beginning-of-line 1)
  (kill-line)
  (yank)
)

Comment: Try the above code. Srsly. `M-w` copies the whole line (unless you make marked a region, then it copies the region). `C-w` kills it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to copy a line:

1. The usual way: <kbd>C-a C-SPC C-n M-w</kbd>
2. With the mouse: triple click on the line, type <kbd>M-w</kbd>
3. Set (or customize) the variable `kill-whole-line` to `t`, then copy by killing and undoing: <kbd>C-a C-k C-_</kbd>

I don't find this a common enough operation that I'd want to assign it a key combination, but if you do then it's easy to write a function:

```
(defun kill-ring-save-line () 
  "Save the line containing point to the kill ring."
  (interactive)
  (kill-ring-save (line-beginning-position) 
                  (line-beginning-position 2)))
```

Comment: I usually use `C-k C-k C-y` which is one keystroke shorter than `C-a C-SPC C-n M-w` and uses less finger acrobatics.

Comment: That only works if point is already at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

C-a C-k C-k C-y
or
C-a C-u 1 C-k C-y

Found via
C-h k C-k
and
C-h f kill-TAB

```
(defun copy-line ()
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-line)
  (kill-line 1)
  (yank))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;; http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WholeLineOrRegion#toc2
;; cut, copy, yank
(defadvice kill-ring-save (around slick-copy activate)
  "When called interactively with no active region, copy a single line instead."
  (if (or (use-region-p) (not (called-interactively-p)))
      ad-do-it
    (kill-new (buffer-substring (line-beginning-position)
                                (line-beginning-position 2))
              nil '(yank-line))
    (message "Copied line")))
(defadvice kill-region (around slick-copy activate)
  "When called interactively with no active region, kill a single line instead."
  (if (or (use-region-p) (not (called-interactively-p)))
      ad-do-it
    (kill-new (filter-buffer-substring (line-beginning-position)
                                       (line-beginning-position 2) t)
              nil '(yank-line))))
(defun yank-line (string)
  "Insert STRING above the current line."
  (beginning-of-line)
  (unless (= (elt string (1- (length string))) ?\n)
    (save-excursion (insert "\n")))
  (insert string))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f2>") 'kill-region)    ; cut.
(global-set-key (kbd "<f3>") 'kill-ring-save) ; copy.
(global-set-key (kbd "<f4>") 'yank)           ; paste.
```